# MSaccess search inconsistent records

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sum, subquery

I have a table INVOICES with columns InvoiceNAME, InvoiceSUM and an other INVOICEitems with column InvoiceNAME, ItemNAME, ItemPRICE and ItemQTY. Tables joined via InvoiceNAME fields.

I'd like to select all the rows from INVOICES table where InvoiceSUM not equals the SUM of ItemPRICE*ItemQTY related to InvoiceNAME. In other words I would like to list the inconsistens records, where the InvoiceSUM not equal to the items total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select i.*
from invoices as i
where i.invoicesum <> (select sum(ii.price * ii.quantity)
                       from INVOICEitems as ii
                       where ii.InvoiceNAME = i.InvoiceNAME
                      );
```

Comment: That is, thanks! (I need to correct i.ItemNAME to i.ID to avoide type mismatch, but works like a charm, thx!)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also display the value from order items in the resultset. If so, a join is more appropriate:

```
select i.*, ii.item_sum
from invoices as i
inner join (
    select invoice_name, sum(item_qty * item_price) as item_sum
    from invoice_items
    group by invoice_name
)  as ii on ii.invoice_name = i.invoice_name
where i.invoice_sum <> ii.item_sum
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolute rights! Thank you for the solution!